# SQL filtering by different conditions based on values in column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a classifier column that can have value of X or Y. My select query has to filter by date taking into account if the column has x or y.

```
date BETWEEN i.valid_fromX AND i.valid_toX 
date BETWEEN i.valid_fromY AND i.valid_toY
```

Essentially I need the equivalent of the following in SQL:

```
if classifier == X {
  check if date is between valid_fromX to valid_toX
}   else if classifier == Y {
  check if date is between valid_fromY to valid_toY
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that with regular and/or logic.  This example searches for January if classifier equals X, and for February if classifier equals Y:

```
where  classifier = 'X' and date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-02-01'
       or
       classifier = 'Y' and date between '2012-02-01' and '2012-03-01'
```

Comment: Why no brackets just in case?

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE  ( classifier = 'X' AND [date] BETWEEN valid_fromX AND valid_toX )
        OR ( classifier = 'Y' AND [date] BETWEEN valid_fromY AND valid_toY )
```

Answer (score 0):

A minor variant:

```
where date between 
           case classifier when 'X' then valid_fromX when 'Y' then valid_fromY end 
           and case classifier when 'X' then valid_toX when 'Y' then valid_toY end
```